# Concatenate with a "," the responses from Rest DataSource in a Copy Activity of Azure Synpase/Data Factory

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I have a copy activity that is using a REST data source to query an API with pagination the response format is JSON and a Azure Data Lake Gen 2 JSON file as the Synk, my issue is that the output of the copy activity is added each rest pagination response JSON object in each line of the output JSON file, making it a not valid JSON file.

in example if the source task of the copy activity query 3 pages from the API the output Json file will look like:

```
{items:[content of page 1]}
{items:[content of page 2]}
{items:[content of page 3]}
```

Sample REST output:

```
{
   items:[
      "property1: "value1",
      "property2: "value2",
      ...
   ]
}
```

I have tried doing this with a loop activity and writing a JSON file for each page/response from the API, but I feel that will incur on many I/O operations and therefore increase the cost.

I would like to format the output (JSON file) to a valid JSON format so it can be consumed for other services, in a single copy activity call:
in example:

```
{items:[
{items:[content of page 1]},
{items:[content of page 2]},
{items:[content of page 3]},
]}
```

**EDIT Screenshots of current configuration**

Copy Activity:
[image: screen shot of copy activity]

Output JSON File
[image: screen shot of output json file]

Answer (score 0):

In order to concatenate all responses with `,` comma, you need to change the file pattern to `Array of Objects`. Below are the steps to change the file pattern.

- Click the **Sink** settings tab of copy activity.
- In File pattern, Select **Array of objects**.  If this value is left blank or Set as `Set of objects`, it stores each Json response in a separate line.

[image]

**Output data when File Pattern is Set of Objects:**
All Json object is stored in a separate line.
[image]

**Output data when File Pattern is Array of Objects:**
All Json objects are concatenated with commas.
[image]

Comment: Hi @Aswin thanks for the response. I have tried with the File pattern Array of objects but I get the same result with Array of objects as with Set of Objects my files end up in the same format. do you there is something wrong with my configuration? I edited the question with screenshots of the current activity

Comment: I have changed only file format. Could you share  screenshots of both file patterns?